# One of the ImageButton not clicking & make HorizontalScrollView clickable

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

This seems to be a very silly problem but its just not working for me.

I have 2 ImageButtons & a HorizontalScrollView(HSV) on a page. Strangely one of the Image Button(1st one) is not clicking. Also I wanted to make the HSV clickable so I used:

`android:clickable="true"`, which does not work

You can use the xml & activity exactly as I have posted.

This is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
 android:id="@+id/topRL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/free_msgs_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="free msgs left" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buy_imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
        />
     </RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/chat_page_listView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
/>

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/chat_message_HSV"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/send_image_button"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/send_image_button"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the activity file:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ImageButton buyIB;
ImageButton sendIB;
HorizontalScrollView chatMessageHSV;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sendIB = (ImageButton) findViewById(
            R.id.send_image_button);
    chatMessageHSV = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(
            R.id.chat_message_HSV);
    buyIB = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buy_imageButton);

    buyIB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "buy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    });

    chatMessageHSV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "hsv", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    sendIB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "send", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}// end of onCreate

}
```

And I cant use button click like

```
public void onClick(View view)
{}
```

because the actual problem is containing a drawer layout where I'm using fragments & there this method doesn't work.

Comment: The solution to ImageButton not clicking, I have mentioned below in an answer. But the HSV problem is still there.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in the `ImageButton` doesn't respond for you click because the `ListView` will respond first for the click because it above the `ImageButton` try to re order it  , when i remove it the `ImageButton` respond for the click

about the `HorizontallScrollView`  i found the solution to use the `Touch Event` instead of `Click` try this code

```
        chatMessageHSV.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                Toast.makeText(ImageButtonActivity.this, "hsv",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                // here code if the touch up
            }

            return false;

        }
    });
```

feed me back

Comment: actually I figured this out immediately after posting the question..thanks anyway.. can you edit your answer & tell me about the HorizontalScrollView

Comment: @PranavMahajan : You can post your answer also, so that it would be helpful for the future visitors

Comment: I just realized that onTouch event for HSV executed the code inside it 4-5 times because on touch triggers the events 4-5 times. I want to execute the code only once

Comment: yes because you need to determine if the action will occurred when the touch down or up  , look the edited answer and feed me back :)

Answer (score 0):

The ImageButton not clicking problem can be solved by adding to ListView these 2 lines:

android:layout_below="@+id/topRL"

android:layout_above="@+id/bottomRL"